# Need to set background of a div with a parameter

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently trying to set the background of my div according to if the user has a chosen background or not, and I can successfully do that to an extend.
However, what I cannot do is set the background of the div via CSS because I cannot concatenate strings in CSS, which means I can for example do:

```
background: url("/uploads/Example.png") !important;
```

But I cannot do.

```
background: url("/uploads/@Model.Banner")
```

or

```
background: url("/uploads/" + @Model.Banner)
```

My current code looks like this.

```
<head>
        @if ("/uploads/" + @Model.Banner != "/uploads/")
        {
        <style>
            :root {
                --url: url("/uploads/@Model.Banner");
}
            .profile-header {
            height: 200px;
            background: var(--url) !important;
                background-size: 100%;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px !important;
                border-radius: 10px !important;
            }
        </style>
        }
        </head>

<div id="main">
    <label class="navigation-bar"><a>Home</a> - <a>Users</a> - <b>Profile</b></label>
    <hr />

    <div class="container profile-header"></div>
```

.profile-header exists in another .css file with a default banner, meaning that the CSS in the code is what would be used for changing it dynamically if a banner exists.

What I kindly ask is for guidance in how I can have set the background of the div to the path + the banner name, the current code does not work as it sets no background to the div when it enters the IF statement. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will know if the user has a value for `Banner` in the Controller action if you are adding it to the `model` for the corresponding View. For example:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    YourModel model = new YourModel();

    ...

    // you could supply a default image or just leave as "url(/uploads/)"
    model.BannerUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Banner) ? "url(/uploads/Default.png)" : $"url(/uploads/{model.Banner})";

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in the View:

```
<head>
@if (!@Model.Banner.Contains("Default.png"))
{
    <style>
        :root {
            --url: @Model.BannerUrl;
         }
        .profile-header {
        height: 200px;
        background: var(--url) !important;
            background-size: 100%;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px !important;
            border-radius: 10px !important;
        }
    </style>
}
</head>

<div id="main">
    <label class="navigation-bar"><a>Home</a> - <a>Users</a> - <b>Profile</b></label>
    <hr />

<div class="profile-header"></div>
```

Or you could add it all inline (just used a couple of styles so you get idea):

```
<div style="background:@Model.BannerUrl !important; height: 200px; background-size: 100%"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

Forgot to say could work in the view as below, but wanted to give alternative option.

```
@{
    var url = $"/uploads/" + @Model.Banner;
}

<div style="background: url(@url) !important"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing, this is the correct answer. Thank you so much!